# how to use the sum-function in xpath?

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

There's the `sum`-function in `xpath`:

```
<list>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
</list>
```

Now with `SimpleXml`...

```
var_dump($xml->xpath("sum(/list/a)"));
```

delivers `NULL` instead of `8`

What's wrong here?

see it not working: https://eval.in/135558

EDIT: I've used this workaround for `SimpleXml` to avoid iterating:

```
$sum = $xml->xpath("/list/a"); 
$sum = array_sum(array_walk("intval", $sum));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using SimpleXML, you're going to have to do it manually. However, you can use DOMDocument to achieve this. Just use [`evaluate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) method to evaluate the XPath expression:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXML($xml); // $xml is the XML string

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$sum = (int) $xpath->evaluate('sum(/list/a)'); // => 8
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/135566)

---

**SimpleXML solution:**

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($xml);
$sum = 0;

foreach ($xml->a as $node) {
    $sum += (int) $node;
}

echo $sum; // => 8
```

[**Demo**](https://eval.in/135568)

Comment: I didn't know before that there is really no way to achieve this with simplexml (because I never tried that). +1 for stating that and another reason to use the `DOM` extension consequently :)

Comment: @AmalMurali for `SimpleXml`, I found `$sum = $xml->xpath("/list/a"); $sum = array_sum(array_walk("intval", $sum));`

Comment: @AmalMurali This is definitely a limit of `SimpleXml`. Usually, I prefer `SimpleXml` a lot over `DOM` for its, well, simplicity.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DOMXPath::evaluate()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.evaluate.php) here:

```
$str = <<<XML
<list>
    <a>1</a>
    <a>3</a>
    <a>4</a>
</list>
XML;

$output = new SimpleXMLElement($str);
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($str);

$selector = new DOMXPath($doc);

var_dump($selector->evaluate('sum(//list/a/text())'));
// double(8)
```

Side-note: It will return a `double` not an `integer`. This might be surprising in the first place.